# Where are the SNS/SMS logs? Cloudwatch empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, sms, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Context: I use Amazon AWS, SNS service, to manually send SMS as a trial before I do any integration by code.

I want to log the SMS reponses (the JSONs that appear here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html ) at some place.

### Investigation done:

It seems I had to create an IAM role. I did it following the steps in the page, in the section "Viewing CloudWatch Logs". The role has been created. The policy for the role contains the following actions:

```
"Action": [
    "logs:CreateLogGroup",
    "logs:CreateLogStream",
    "logs:PutLogEvents",
    "logs:PutMetricFilter",
    "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"
],
```

I have set the "Default percentage of success to sample" to the `100%` so it should log all errors and successes...

And now what? I have sent a couple of SMSs, I go to the Cloudwatch / Logs and all is empty.

### Questions:

- Where are the logs?
- Do I have to do anything else with the IAM to get that logged?
- Do I have to do anything in the Cloudwatch section?
- Where is it supposed I should be able to see the logs?

I've spent 6+ hours with this and I want to think it is some silly point I'm missing. It can't be so complicated.

The overall question is **Where are the SNS/SMS logs and how do I activate them?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if your AIM configuration is good or wrong, I would need to check your configuration in order to tell you that, but if you want to know where the SNS logs are, in my case I can find them doing:

- Go to CloudWatch
- From the left menu, select Logs
- You will see the list of your logs, search for the name of your SNS, in my case is something like `sns/us-west-2/<account-id>/app/APNS/<endpoint-name>`
- After you click on that name, you will find all your logs

Image attached:
[image]

Comment: In my Logs I can only see one "Log Group" that I created manually. Is it supposed that the SMS will create the "Log Group" automatically? I don't see any `sns/{zone}/{id}/{more-things}` like yours. How do I get the `SNS` subsystem to create the "Log Group" and start logging?

Comment: With respect to your comment "I don't know if your AIM configuration is good or wrong" => What I see is that the `SNS` created an `IAM Role` named `SNSSuccessFeedback` and it bound itself to the role. But there is not any user created related to this. Is it enough that the `SNS` is bound to the role? Do I need to manually create a "dummy user" with this role?

Comment: So the thing is that... for some reason, seems that there could be "internal delays", and the 2 test SMS I sent did not trigger the creation of the log group. Today (2 days later) I sent a third SMS and it triggered the creation of the LogGroup. I can see the event logged there! Thanks Max.

Comment: Hey Xavi! That's great, glad you found the issue in there. While reading your first 2 messages I was going to say that when something similar happened to me was because they SNS messages were not being triggered at all, so it seems it could be because of that, or because of the delay you mentioned.